# incorrect lens definition in Edward Kmett's presentation?

Tags: haskell

I'm slowly trying to wrap my head around how the `lens` package works.  I'm reading Edward's slides (http://comonad.com/haskell/Lenses-Folds-and-Traversals-NYC.pdf) and I have a question about the definition of `Store s a` on slides 8 and 9:

```
newtype Lens s a = Lens (s -> Store s a)
data Store s a = Store (s -> a) s
```

Is the definition backwards?  If lenses are pairs of getters and setters, it seems to me that `Store s a` should be defined as:

```
data Store s a = Store (a -> s) a
```

where the first constructor parameter is the setter (put an `a` and return the `s` data structure) and the second is the getter (fetch the `a` from the `s` data structure).

Can anyone confirm if it's an error in the slides, or if my understanding is incorrect, please explain.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that looks like an error. But `Store` is correct -- it's a standard comonad. The definition of `Lens` should be `newtype Lens s a = Lens (s -> Store a s)`.

Comment: Ah, it is infact `Store a s`; I misread.  Sorry for the confusion :(